# Check for potential side-effects of method without changing anything Pythonically

Tags: python, oop

Right now, I have the following class methods:

```
def check_capacity(self, at_index)
def update_capacity(self, at_index)
```

The former returns a Boolean, while the latter changes an instance variable. The problem is both methods do very similar things. I feel like I'm violating DRY?

I'd like to have one method:

```
def update_capacity(self, at_index)
```

which I can use as:

```
if update_capacity(at_index):
```

that would create the intended side-effects if the side-effects are desirable, and return False otherwise.

My attempt was to copy the instance variable, check to see if the copy was desirably changed, and then set the instance variable to the copy if correct and return True, or don't and return False otherwise. However, this doesn't work with mutable data structures (like lists)!

Should I just be doing this with a "deep copy"? Or is there a better way to go about doing this? I'd like to be as Pythonic as possible.

**EDIT**

The `check_capacity` iterates through the instance variable and checks if making the change would violate a condition.

The `update_capacity` iterates through the instance variable and makes the change, knowing the condition won't be violated.

Both have very similar code.

Comment: Not entirely sure what you're trying to do, but would a `property` help?

Comment: "The former returns a Boolean, while the latter changes an instance variable." This does not sound like they are doing the same thing to me. I don't understand why do you want to merge the two methods.

Comment: Can you please provide more information what those two methods do and what they have in common.

Comment: Do you ever call one method without calling the other one near it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a hunch that those two functions together manage to straddle your problem without exactly hitting it on the head. If I have this right, you want to have `update_capacity` either change something or return `False` if changing something is not desired.

It seems to me that you will be able to achieve this functionality by adding the checking mechanism from `check_capacity` into `update_capacity`, performing the condition check before executing the body of `update_capacity`:

```
def update_capacity(self, at_index):
    if <condition from check_capacity>:
        <body of update_capacity>
    else:
        return False
```

Of course, this code will return `None` if the condition is true, so if you want to keep your function signatures tidy, you could return `True` or something depending on what fits the rest of your code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Sorry that my edit wasn't clearer: the update_capacity function is modifying things in an iterator. The check_capacity function goes through the iterator and makes sure the condition isn't violated ANYWHERE in the iterator. Thus, the iterator passed to update_capacity may fail to meet the condition e.g. half-way through the iterator, but by that point the first half of the iterator is modified, when it shouldn't have been! Is this helpful?

Comment: You could go through the iterator twice in the same function.

Answer (score 0):

If `check_capacity` is applied to more than one places, make it
a decorator that makes sure it throws an exception if the constraint/check
is not met.

Like

```
@check_capacity
def update_capacity(...)
    # Does the job and does not return anything
```

If `check_capacity` is not used anywhere else, just put the logic inside
`update_capacity`.

Edit:
Also this

> if update_capacity(at_index):

is ambiguous at best. Is the function going to see if I can update? Is it going to actually update/mutate something?

It is evident that these 2 functions must be separate.

Comment: Why is it better to use a decorator over keeping the logic inside `update_capacity`?

Comment: It is a common technique to separate orthogonal problems. So it is not always a better way. It depends a lot on the big picture of his code, which I don't have. BTW what you suggested(about returning True/False), it is not good practice or pythonic. When you mutated a structure you should not return anything(see for example the python built-in structures and their methods). `if update_capacity(..)` is ambiguous and wrong. There should be a  different method that checks the capacity(returning True/False) and another one which mutates the capacity(returning None).

Comment: That doesn't answer my question - *why* is it a common technique? What makes it superior? My instinct is to say it improves readability and can DRY out repetitive code, but is that all there is to it?

Comment: 1) It doesn't make it superior by default. Please read again the *first line* of my answer to the poster and my comment to you. 2) Your instinct is basically correct. Additionally you can keep the logic of distinct functions/procedures unrelated. e.g. the `check_capacity`'s logic/code might change without changing at all the inner code of `update_capacity`. Plus you can chain decorators on top of each other. That would be useful if we had many "constraints". Django uses decorators extensively, @login_required and `@user_passes_test` are good examples to check if you want.

Comment: Thank you rantanplan. Your answer is essentially what I'm doing. However, I feel like I'm violating DRY. My check_capacity goes through an iterator and sees IF modifying each object of the iterator  would ever break the condition. If it does anywhere, update_capacity shouldn't be called. However, check_capacity and update_capacity have very similar code since update_capacity is making the modifications that check_capacity is just checking. Sorry for the ambiguous function names -- they are mostly irrelevant. I'm trying to abstract to the side-effects part of the functions.

Comment: @jakecar I understand. Though it is hard to propose alternate solutions since I don't know the specific `conditions` and what mutations the `update` actually does. If it is possible to provide more concrete code, I'd be happy to think it over.